# Eclipse issues with Java 8 and Struts2.5

Tags: java, eclipse

I have setup Eclipse to create Webapplication with Struts. Following are the version info:

Struts 2.5.10
eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64
apache-tomcat-7.0.75-windows-x64

When I change the Installed JRE to point to Java 8, I start getting a compilation error on  the package declaration of the Java Action Class which says:

The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required.class File.

Any help on resolving this issue will be appreciated

Souvik

Answer (score 0):

Set the System Variable Path to point to bin folder of your Java 1.8 installation. Set the System Variable JAVA_HOME to the directory just before bin folder of the installation. Please restart Eclipse after this. This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have also set JDK properly along with JRE.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are using obsolete version of eclipse.

Eclipse started supporting JAVA 1.8 with the version 4.4(Eclipse Luna).

So if you decided to use JAVA 1.8 you better to start using `Eclipse Luna` are later versions.